# FTP batch report with chinese characters to excel

Tags: ftp, mainframe

We have a requirement to FTP the batch report to a excel sheet in .csv format. The batch report contains both single byte and double byte characters, for example, English and Chinese. The data in mainframe is in Base64 format and when this is FTP’ed in either Binary or ASCII mode, the resulting .csv spreadsheet shows only junk characters. We need a method to FTP the batch report file, so that the FTP’ed report is in readable format.

Request your help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Chinese character sets but I would think if you're not restricted to CSV, you might try to format an XML document for excel whereby you can specify the fonts as part of the spreadsheet definition.

Assuming that isn't an option I would think the Base64 format might need to be translated to ASCII (from EBCDIC) before transmission and then delivered in BINARY.  Otherwise you risk having the data translated to something you didn't expect.

Another way to see what is really happening is send the data as ASCII and retrieve the data as BINARY and then compare the before and after results to see what characters were changed enroute during transmission.  I recall having to do something similar to this once to resolve different code sets in Europe vs. U.S.

I'm not sure any of these suggestions would represent a "solution" to your problem, but these would be ideas that I would explore.  I would be interested in hearing how you resolve this.